# Безнадёжный или безнадежный?

Tags: фонетика

Какой вариант предпочтительнее: безнадёжный или безнадежный? В словарях разрешают оба варианта, но, например, Пушкин в своих стихах использовал второй вариант. Особенно мне интересна краткая форма этого прилагательного.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пушкина не берите в расчет. В те времена современные нормы в отношении Ё еще не совсем устоялись. Мало того, в стихах часто применялся "высокий" слог, предполагающий, помимо прочего, использование церковнославянских - и вообще исторических - форм, где Ё просто не было.
Короче, у Пушкина везде Е, не заморачивайтесь:

Исчез властитель осужденный,
Могучий баловень побед,
И для изгнанника вселенной
Уже потомство настает.
("Наполеон")

А насчет словарей - не знаю, где могли найти "безнадЕжен". 
Никаких вариантов, только через Ё. Краткая форма - безнадЁжен.

~~~~

Поправил цитату, нехорошо все-таки Пушкина перевирать, пусть и в самой малости.
Кстати, насчет "безнадежного" Пушкина... Тут еще одна сложность. Ё перед шипящими - вообще редкость, во времена Пушкина - тем более.

Answer (score 0):

хм, отнюдь, словари словарями, Я не знаю, но театры говорят безнадЕжность, кого как ни их учат правильному русскому языку!

Comment: Возможно, так говорят в старых пьесах, где так говорить надо, потому что автор именно так и написал.

Comment: Какой театр, какая пьеса, какие актеры?!

Comment: Ну что Вы, в старых пьесах это как раз правильно. В словаре Ушакова найдем оба варианта как равноправные. У Аванесова безнадЕжный дано с пометой допустимо устаревающее. На сегодняшний день скорее устаревшее, в словарях Ё.